# Arithmetic Sequence problem involving terms of the sequence and the value of that term

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The full question is here:

In an arithmetic sequence, the first term is $2$ and the second term is $5$. Term number $N$ of
the sequence has a value of $M$, such that $M$ is the largest two-digit number in the sequence.
What is the value of $M + N$?

I tried to make a possible sequence and solve that problem from there but have no success, in fact I kind of don't understand where to start. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first two elements of the sequence, the arithmetic sequence must be of the form $(x_n)$ with $x_n = 3n-1$.

The largest 2-digit number in this sequence is $3 \cdot 33-1=98$, and so $M+N = 98+33 = 131$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given that $$a_1=2,a_2=5$$ so we get
$$5=2+d$$ so $$d=3$$ and you will get $$a_N=2+(N-1)\cdot 3=M$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

So, $100>2+(N-1)(5-2)\iff3N<100-2+3$

$\implies N<101/3<34$

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is the following :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \quad u_n = 2 + 3(n-1)$$

It consists of all the numbers that are equal to $2$ modulo $3$ : in the $90$-numbers, you have $92$, $95$, and $98$.

So the biggest is $M= 98$, and you have $u_N = M$ if and only if
$$2 + 3(N-1)= 98, \quad i.e. \quad N=33$$

So $$N+M = 131$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

In an arithmetic sequence you always have

$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+d
$$

so you can figure out what $d$ is.

Furthermore

$$
a_{M}=a_1+(M-1)\cdot d
$$

Hope I could help